# Combine and reduce land cover and MODIS collections with different IDs

Tags: google-earth-engine, modis, land-cover, land-classification, land-use

I need to add the information from Land cover Image Collection (2015-2019) to MODIS Image collection. In practice should be merged fuve land cover images with MODIS images for the whole five year long period. I tried to merge them without result because of IDs error. And I tried to add pictures one by one to MODIS collection. In this case when I print info for 2020, theoretically I can't have an info about land cover but I have it anyway from one of added images. How can I make an order in this mixed collection?

````
var collection = mod.filterBounds(buffer)
                            .filterDate('2020-01-01', '2021-01-01')
                            .select(['LST_Day_1km', 'Day_view_time', 'Day_view_angle']);
   


var filtered_scaled = collection.map(function(image) {
  var buffer = station.buffer(564.2);
  var lc18 = lc2018.select('discrete_classification').copyProperties(image, ['discrete_classification']);
  var lc19 = lc2019.select('discrete_classification').copyProperties(image, ['discrete_classification']);
  var lc17 = lc2017.select('discrete_classification').copyProperties(image, ['discrete_classification']);
  var lc16 = lc2016.select('discrete_classification').copyProperties(image, ['discrete_classification']);
  var lc15 = lc2015.select('discrete_classification').copyProperties(image, ['discrete_classification']);
  return image.addBands(lc18, null, true)
              .addBands(lc19, null, true)
              .addBands(lc17, null, true)
              .addBands(lc16, null, true)
              .addBands(lc15, null, true)
              .clip(buffer);
});

var nImages = filtered_scaled.size();
var ImageList = filtered_scaled.toList(nImages);
var img_indices = ee.List.sequence(0,nImages.subtract(1));
function reduceAndPrint(index) {
  var nomScale4 = filtered_scaled.select('discrete_classification').first().projection().nominalScale();
  var buffer = station.buffer(564.2); // CALCULATION LST BUFFER
  var image = ee.Image(ImageList.get(index));
var lc = image.select('discrete_classification').reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.median(),
      maxPixels: 1e9,
      scale: nomScale4,
      geometry: buffer
    });
return lc.get('discrete_classification');```
````

Comment: Do you want to merge the land cover image of 2019 with the modis 2019 image? Or want the land cover info using the reducer from 2015-2019 to be merged with each modis image irrespective of the year?

Comment: @Padmanabha Hello! The final goal are statistics after application of reducers. So at the end I need a table with information about all images captured during 5 years. And for everyone of them I need to have an information about land cover. I can't make a composite for the whole year.